# How to stop Hydra from creating the subfolder at the default output folder?

Tags: python

I managed to stop hydra from generating the log file in the subfolder at the defaults' outputs folder. However the sub folder is still generated.

Here is the yaml file:

```
defaults:
  - override hydra/hydra_logging: disabled
  - override hydra/job_logging: disabled
  - _self_

hydra:
  output_subdir: null
```

This is the program that uses the yaml file above:

```
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig


@hydra.main(config_path='conf', config_name='test2config', version_base=None)
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
# def main():

    print("Current working directory:", Path.cwd())

    log_dir = Path(r'//xxx/xx')

    # Define the log file path
    log_file_path = log_dir / 'your_log_file.log'

    # Set up logging to the file specified in the config
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_path, level=logging.DEBUG)

    # Log some messages
    logging.debug("This is a debug message")
    logging.info("This is an info message")
    logging.warning("This is a warning message")
    logging.error("This is an error message")
    logging.critical("This is a critical message")

    logging.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```